# Java TimerTask , wont stop when cancel is called

Tags: timertask

So...

I'm creating a plugin.

I have a main Class called Basics

Globally in Basics I create:

```
static Timer enterdungeon = new Timer();
static Timer finddungeon = new Timer();
static Timer lootdungeon = new Timer();
```

Also I have a class named task

the enterdungeon timer is a fixed period of time, and seems to work as expected when used.
As is the same for thee lootdungeon timer.

The finddungeon timer can be interrupted IF an event in basics is triggered.

The event DOES trigger fine
the top line in this event is:
    finddungeon.cancel();

after it starts the lootdungeon timer.

the problem is the finddungeon timer does not cancel, it continues to run, below is the task class:

```
import java.util.TimerTask;
import me.boduzapho.Basics.DoWarp.Returner;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

public class task extends TimerTask
{
private final Player _player;
private final int ticks;
private int cnt = 0;
private final int _sec;
private final String _message;

public task(Player player, int sec, String message)
{
    this._player = player;
    this._sec = sec;
    this._message = message;
    this.ticks = sec;
}

private void timetoloot(Player p)
{

    p.sendMessage("SUCCESS! Nice Job, Enjoy the loot!");
    Returner loc1 = DoWarp.getwarp("launch", Basics.warps, Basics.wx,Basics.wy, Basics.wz, p);
    DoWarp.warpme(loc1.x, loc1.y, loc1.z, p, false, Basics.plugin);

}

private void failedwhiteblock(Player p)
{
    p.sendMessage("FAIL! You did not find the white block. Sending you back. TRY AGAIN!");
    Returner loc1 = DoWarp.getwarp("launch", Basics.warps, Basics.wx, Basics.wy, Basics.wz, p);
    DoWarp.warpme(loc1.x, loc1.y, loc1.z, p, false, Basics.plugin);

}

private void enterdungeon(Player p)
{
    Basics.Stage.setLine(3, "Off you Go!");
    Basics.Stage.update();
    Basics.Stage.setLine(0, "");
    Basics.Stage.setLine(1, "");
    Basics.Stage.setLine(2, "");
    Basics.Stage.setLine(3, "");
    Basics.Stage.update();

    Basics.cDoClear(p);
    Basics.cDoSpawners(p);
    Basics.cDoRed(p);
    Returner loc1 = DoWarp.getwarp("dstart", Basics.warps, Basics.wx, Basics.wy, Basics.wz, p);
    DoWarp.warpme(loc1.x, loc1.y, loc1.z, p, false, Basics.plugin);
    Basics.DungeonPlayer = p;
    p.sendMessage("Welcome to the Dungeon, you have 1 minuite to locate and click the white block.");
    p.sendMessage("If you fail you will be returned to spawn. If you find it the treasures will be revieled");
    p.sendMessage("and the monsters banished for 1 min so you can loot the chests! After which you will");
    p.sendMessage("Be warped back to spawn with your Loot!");
    Basics.finddungeon.schedule(new task(_player, 30, "Time left to find the WHITE block :"), 0, 1000);
    Basics.enterdungeon.cancel();
}

@Override
public void run()
{
    while (cnt < ticks)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
            _player.sendMessage(_message + " " + Integer.toString(_sec - cnt));
            ++cnt;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    _player.sendMessage("Done!");
    if (_message == "Time left:")
    {
        enterdungeon(_player);
    }

    if (_message == "Time left to find the WHITE block :")
    {
        failedwhiteblock(_player);
    }

    if (_message == "Time left to LOOT:")
    {
        timetoloot(_player);
    }

    //

    return;

}
}
```

Here is the function called in Basics (main class) that is supposed to cancel the finddungeon timer.

```
// white block in dungeon
        if (DungeonPlayer == player)
        {
            if ((block != null) && (block.getType() == Material.WOOL))
            {
                player.sendMessage("Canceling finddungeon from Basics");
                finddungeon.cancel();
                cDoClear(player);
                cDoChests(player);

                player.sendMessage("Congradulations! Time to Loot your rewards for finding the White Block!");
                Timer lootdungeon = new Timer();
                lootdungeon.schedule(new task(player, 10, "Time left to LOOT:"), 0, 1000);

                return;
                // ***
            }
        }
```

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: I tried to globally declare a boolean variable that is checked inside the run event of the timer. I set this to false by default, and this instructs the time to continue. When the white block event is triggered i set this to true, to indicate to the run event to call cancel (as per the instructions from java, as a fool proof way to kill the timer).  This also does not work. I can see through reflected "chat" the timer boolean variable is changing from false to true and the cancel(); is being called but the timer just keeps going.

Answer (score 1):

Cause TimerTask.cancel doesn't do anything to the active task, it just clears the scheduler. You'll have to override cancel method, or just use this as a starting point:

```
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
    private volatile Thread thread;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        thread = Thread.currentThread();
        //do your task and keep your eye on InterruptedException when doing Sleeps, Waits
        //also check Thread.interrupted()
    }

    public boolean cancel() {
        Thread thread = this.thread;
        if (thread != null) {
            thread.interrupt();
        }
        return super.cancel();
    }
}
```